# Исполняется команда после нажатия сочетаний клавиш

Tags: python

У меня есть такой код:

```
import msvcrt
pressedKey = msvcrt.getch() 
if ord(pressedKey) == ord(""): # нужно сделать сочетание клавиш l + s
    print("F")
```

Надо, чтобы команда print исполнялась после сочетания клавиш l + s, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример использования библиотеки keyboard:

```
# pip install keyboard
import keyboard

keyboard.add_hotkey('l + s', lambda: print('F'))
```